# Страницы php с переданными параметрами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос: страницы php с переданными параметрами считаются как отдельные страницы?

Comment: Для браузера и для веб-сервера - да

Comment: @AlexWindHope для веб сервера как раз таки нет. если только переадресация не настроена.

Comment: Вы не так меня поняли, ок, допустим если настроить кеширование - страница /lol.php и страница /lol.php?test это 2 разные страницы в кеше. Нужно правильно понимать что такое **страница** и что такое скрипт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да считаются разными, и не только *.php, на этом и основан один из костылей для подключения файла стилей.

```
<link href="style.css?2134321" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Это наверно, фича, а не костыль :) Очень удобно, когда выставляешь номер версии css, js и вообще любой статики, которую обычно надо кэшировать, но она может измениться.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думала, но были сомнения.